# Count all files in a directory and its subdirectories

Tags: c++, visual-c++

As part of an application I'm working on, I need to count all the files in a directory and it's subdirectories. I've written a recursive function, however it strangely doesn't count all the files in large directories - it works fine on smaller ones though.

*On a directory with 16 files(8 of which in subdirs) it worked fine, but when testing it on 8000 files in about 500 folders it stopped the count at 760 files.*

The code is:

```
void RecursiveSearch(wchar_t* param, int* pFiles)
{
HANDLE hFind;
WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;

wchar_t* junk = new wchar_t [2];
StringCchPrintf(junk,2,L".");
wchar_t* path = new wchar_t [MAX_PATH];
StringCchPrintf(path,MAX_PATH,L"%s\\*",param);

hFind = FindFirstFile(path,&wfd);

    do {
        if (wfd.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
            wchar_t* tpath = new wchar_t [MAX_PATH];
            StringCchPrintf(tpath,MAX_PATH,L"%s%s\\*",param,wfd.cFileName);
            if (wfd.cFileName[0] == junk[0]) {
                delete [] tpath; //filter for '.' directories
            } else {
                RecursiveSearch(tpath,pFiles);
                delete [] tpath;
            }
        } else {
            ++*pFiles;
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind,&wfd) == TRUE);

delete [] junk, param, path;
return;
}
```

'param' passes the filepath (without \) and 'pFiles' is a pointer to an int that contains the file count.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've read a few similiar posts here but none of them seem to deal with this particular issue.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Does it stop at a particular nesting level?

Comment: Is MAX_PATH big enough? Perhaps also check the return code of StringCchPrintf().

Comment: This code looks messy with those new and delete []. If boost is not ruled out (really should be no reason), have a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html

Comment: Also, I see there is a call to `RecursiveSearch1()` inside your `RecursiveSearch()`. What does that function do? Are you showing us your real code?

Comment: @Andy Prowl - That's a typo, I changed the function name when posting here. Theres no. 1 and 2 in the application, but 2 isn't related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem, it looks like the * weren't removed when adding a new directory name, resulting in incorrect paths. The improved code is below.

```
void RecursiveSearch(wchar_t* param, int* pFiles)
{
HANDLE hFind;
WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;

wchar_t* junk= new wchar_t [2];
StringCchPrintf(junk,2,L".");
wchar_t* path = new wchar_t [MAX_PATH];
StringCchPrintf(path,MAX_PATH,L"%s*",param);

hFind = FindFirstFile(path,&wfd);

    do {
        if (wfd.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
            wchar_t* tPath = new wchar_t [MAX_PATH];

            //Remove misplaced stars
            wchar_t* locator = new wchar_t [2];
            StringCchPrintf(locator,2,L"\\");
            wchar_t* cleanParam = new wchar_t [MAX_PATH];
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PATH; i++) {
                if (param[MAX_PATH-i] == locator[0]) {
                    StringCchPrintf(cleanParam,(MAX_PATH-i)+2,L"%s",param);
                    break;
                }
            }

            StringCchPrintf(tPath,MAX_PATH,L"%s%s\\*",cleanParam,wfd.cFileName);
            if (wfd.cFileName[0] == junk[0]) {
                delete [] tPath;
            } else {
                RecursiveSearch(ebx,pFiles);
                delete [] tPath;
            }
        }
        else{
            ++*pFiles;
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind,&wfd) == TRUE);

delete [] junk, param, path;
return;
}
```

Thanks for your comment Andy Prowl - you got me looking in the right place :)